# Returning windows.h HANDLE to Java JNI

Tags: java, c, windows, serial-port, java-native-interface

I have a method which creates serial port connections in C language for which we use a window HANDLE type like,

```
hCom = CreateFile( portNo,
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
                NULL, // no security attributes
                OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
                0,    // not overlapped I/O
                NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
                );
```

So on a specific port number I am creating the connection. Now I want to return this HANDLE type to my JNI .h program. So that next time I could do operations with the HANDLE type like 
 **Sending/receiving through the object** which will have this HANDLE encapsulated.

But I am unable to write the JNI equivalent of this HANDLE type and how to save it to Java Object. Can anyone please help out in this ?
Also if it's possible can we further throw DCB type from same Windows.h file and handle it in JNI object

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the definition of HANDLE:

```
typedef void * HANDLE;
```

As a void pointer is not some complex memory structure, it can be declared in Java as a `long`. For 32-bit architecture and `int` would be enough, but if you just use a `long` 32-bit and 64-bit will fit.

DCB is a structure. To use it in Java you can transfer a byte array, but you will have to know (i. e. calculate from the header file) the index of each struct member to be able to access it. Might be clearer if you create a dedicated Java object for the transfer and copy the struct values in your C code.

Comment: *DCB is a structure* True, but `HANDLE` is a `void *`, so it's impossible to dereference it.  You could force it to be a pointer to a specific structure by casting, but that ties the code to a specific version of the structure - which was likely deliberately hidden for both portability across OS versions and so internal changes wouldn't require recompiling the code.  Just passing the `HANDLE` value around as a `jlong` is probably a lot safer.